# One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, caml

Trying to use a CAML query for the first time but getting this error. Heres my query:

```
"<Where>
<And>                                                
<And>
<And>
<And>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='Groupx0020Name'/>
<Value Type='Text'>" + groupName + "</Value>
</Eq>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='Arrived'/>
<Value Type='Boolean'>False</Value>
</Eq>
</And>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='Plant'/>
<Value Type='Text'>" + Plant + "</Value>
</Eq>
</And>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='Arrivalx0020date'/>
<Value Type='Text'>" + arrivalDate + "</Value>
</Eq>
</And>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='Left site'/>
<Value Type='Boolean'>False</Value>" +
</Eq>
</And>
</Where>";
```

I used a CAML designer to generate this query but still no luck any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was my content for the Plant field I had it set to text but the correct syntax was 'choice' as it was a drop down list value. I hope this helps anyone else with the same problem